# Coredata - “NSObjectInaccessibleException - CoreData could not fulfill a fault”

Tags: ios, core-data

i have a problem in my iOS App, i receive this error:

```
“NSObjectInaccessibleException - CoreData could not fulfill a fault”
```

When i update the database, i do it from another thread and i have in that thread this method:

```
@interface UpdateDatabase : NSOperation

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation UpdateDatabase

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appController managedObjectContext];

// Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
[mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                              withObject:notification
                           waitUntilDone:YES];  
}


- (void)main {

    AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
    [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appController persistentStoreCoordinator]];

    // Register context with the notification center
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:self.managedObjectContext];

    [self checkForUpdate:self.name];

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Serial" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNumber" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNumber" cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
        Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

        abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
} 

- (void)checkForUpdate:(NSString *)name 
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Serial" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //Controllo prima che la serie di cui voglio fare l'aggiornamento non sia in download, e non stia facendo già un aggiornamneto (caso mai per qualche strana ragione non ne siano partiti 2), prendo solo le altre.
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"serialName",self.name]];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
        //i update the object
    }

    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
        // You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful
        // during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert
        // panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
        //
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
@end
```

and i launch a new nsoperation for every element in the core data database, then in the view where i have the UITableView, i have this:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Set up the fetched results controller.
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Serial" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNumber" ascending:NO];

    NSSortDescriptor *numberDayDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"numberOfDays" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *serialNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"serialName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,numberDayDescriptor,serialNameDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNumber" cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
        Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

        abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}    

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Sometime the app crashes and some time don't crash, how i can handle this error? i have read some question about this problem on SO, and someone talk about remove the fetchbatchsize and the cache, what you think? where i wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have edited the code.

Comment: Could you clarify this senetnce *When i update the database, i do it from another thread and i have in that thread this method:*? Is `main` a method of `NSOperation` class? Move that code where you set up core data stack.

Comment: Please, also remove `NSFetchedREsultsController` delegate methods, since they are not useful in question resolution. Too much code ;-)

Comment: i have edited all the question, i have add more code, and i add also the nsfetchedresulcontroller also for the nsoperation, because i don't if the problem it's about the fetchbatchsize and the cache in fetchedcontroller method, what you think?

Comment: On what versions of iOS are you seeing the crash? NSFetchedResultsController specifically on some older versions has some issues that could contribute.

Comment: Also, are you DELETING managed objects anyplace in your code, background or otherwise?

Comment: i got that error from a ios 6 version, and i don't think i'm deleting a managed object in my code...

Comment: Most typically, the fault message occurs when you have a reference to an MO that is deleted in another MOC... So like if your front-end UI had a reference to something that was deleted in a background thread... When the fault fires, that exception bubbles up.